# Set properties on DOM elements happen to be undefined again if I include Polymer Platform on a existing library

Tags: javascript, object, polymer, platform, shadow-dom

### The issue's impact

I have a proprietary library and custom elements to make settings on the library. Separately the library is running fine and so do my custom elements.

As soon ***as I include platform, the functionality of the library gets broken*** due to missing data. I figured out that set (custom) properties on DOM elements happen to be `undefined` again where they are expected to still hold set data. At least ***if platform is not included, the properties hold a defined value***.

The issue is given within Firefox 32 and Internet Explorer 11.

Chrome 37 is not affected, suprisingly not even with `polymer-dev` sources and `Platform = {flags: {debug: true, log: 'data', register: true, shadow: 'polyfill'}}`.

### Backgrounds explained

Platform wraps objects to polyfill functionality i.e. ShadowDOM. So I falsely assumed the wrappers to lose set properties by being exchanged/renewed or to do not delegate properly, however the wrappers stay the same.

As pointed out by *kentaromiura* within the #polymer IRC channel on freenode and by *Scott* in the comment below, ***platform*** basically ***needs to wrap every element, but there are*** bound to be ***cases where polymer does not wrap***. See [ShadowDOM#wrap-and-unwrap](https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM#wrap-and-unwrap) and [ShadowDOM#known-limitations](https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM#known-limitations):

> #### Known limitations
>
> - `document`, `window`, `document.body`, `document.head` and others are non configurable and cannot be overridden. We are trying to make these work as seamlessly as possible but there will doubtlessly be cases where there will be problems; for those cases you can use `wrap` and `unwrap` to get unblocked.

Having platform included, within the library ***problems occur where*** there is still access to unwrapped elements (access via  `document.body`, `document.head`) and therefore ***data is registered or read upon unwrapped DOM elements***. [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916868/set-properties-on-dom-elements-happen-to-be-undefined-again-if-i-include-polymer/25917504#25917504) supposed so.

## Possible workarounds

Within IRC *kentaromiura* added to workaround this by:

> *[17:57:27] kentaromiura a)* [his] preferred method: using selectors instead of pointer
>
> *[17:57:46] kentaromiura b)* if not possible for any reason use the wrap/unwrap method https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM#wrap-and-unwrap

where ***b)*** would be "very discouraged by the polymer guys".
Also [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916868/set-properties-on-dom-elements-happen-to-be-undefined-again-if-i-include-polymer/25917504#25917504) demonstrates the selector based workaround ***a)*** in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916868/set-properties-on-dom-elements-happen-to-be-undefined-again-if-i-include-polymer/25917504#25917504).

---

### I am still facing a problem

Apparently listeners are also affected in some way and since the library organizes and visualizes graphs on DOM heavy operations, platform should not engage this for performance reasons.

A new issue will be referenced here soon, where I try to get platform running on just a subtree of custom elements.

Polymer/platform is still great and fun to be used. Thank you all for the help! :)

Comment: Generally you want to use wrapped objects 100% of the time. If there is a place you are getting an unwrapped object, that could be a point of failure, try to find if this is happening. (Fwiw, there are a few known ways this can happen, e.g. the `window.document` and `window.document.body` references cannot be wrapped by the Polyfill for security reasons). The other potential problem is you are using some API that doesn't like wrapped objects. If you find either of these kinds of problems, we can try to help you workaround them.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'm not able to reproduce. The below code behaves the same for me in Firefox 32, Safari 7, and Chrome 37. Would it be possible to provide a [minimal, viable, and complete example of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

One thought that occurs to me is that you may be ending up with a mix of wrapped and unwrapped elements (the polymer platform needs to wrap all DOM objects in some situations, I think when polyfilling the Shadow DOM).

```html
<script src='http://polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js'></script>

<script>
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.setAttribute('id', 'myElem');
  elem.customProperty = 'hello world';
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  
  var elemFromDoc = document.querySelector('#myElem');
  var wasPreserved = (elemFromDoc.customProperty === elem.customProperty);
  document.write('Custom property value: ' + elemFromDoc.customProperty);
  document.write('<br>Custom property preserved? ' + wasPreserved);
</script>
```